# spotify client on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: spotify, 15.04

Spotify stopped working after upgrading to the 15.04 (beta):

> spotify: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any tips?

Comment: 15.04 is still not released as stable, and is not supported here until it is released.

Comment: The askubuntu.com policy prevents posting questions on the future ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution : I downloaded the libgcrypt11 library for Debian Wheezy and installed it via

```
dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This solved the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work on the 15.04 release as of 4/23 (day of release), anybody had success with this yet? (on the public build)

Comment: Installing old security libraries (libgcrypt.so.11) is not recommended. This version runs fine with Ubuntu 15-10: http://repository-origin.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify-client/